# How to access array property on JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This is very strange, but I just can't access a property which is an array of objects on a given JavaScript object. I've already outputted on Chrome's console the object itself and the attempt to access the property, and the result leads me to more confusion. 
Here's what I've received on the Chrome's console about an object present on `var` named `quest`:

```
[Object]
0: Object
    FuncaoValNum: ""
    IDQuestaoMultiplaEscolha: 0
    Opcoes: Array[2]
        0: Object
            IDOpcaoQuestaoMultiplaEscolha: 0
            IDQuestaoMultiplaEscolha: "0"
            Ordem: 0
            Texto: "Op1"
            (...)
            __proto__: Object
        1: Object
            IDOpcaoQuestaoMultiplaEscolha: 0
            IDQuestaoMultiplaEscolha: "0"
            Ordem: 1
            Texto: "Op2"
            (...)
            __proto__: Object
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array[0]
    (...)
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

and on the following line of outputting the above info, I just try to access the object's `Opcoes` array's length by using `quest.Opcoes.length`. The result is:

```
undefined
```

Really confused about it as it seems that `quest` is an object with an array property named `Opcoes` with 2 other objects on it, and yet, I just can't access it's `.length` with `quest.Opcoes.length` or any other way that I could think of.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outermost structure is also an Array, so you need to access the first index of that array to get to the object.

```
quest[0].Opcoes.length
```

---

When you did this:

```
quest.Opcoes.length
```

you should actually get a *TypeError* instead of `undefined` since `quest` has no `Opcoes` property, meaning `.length` would be accessing a property on `undefined`.

Comment: Well, don't know why it is outputting an "undefined", but for now, I'm really glad that It worked... I was missing that it was in fact an array. Thanks a LOT! Kind of thing that only an external eye can catch! :D

Answer (score 1):

Just

`data[0].Opcoes`

(attribute `Opcoes`of the first row of your object)